# Changing the target version of TypeScript Code causes the TypeScript Compiler to no find the module anymore

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, tsc

I have signalr installed via npm in Visual Studio 2019.
When i have target on ES6 in my compiler options I get the error `TS2307 (TS) Cannot find mogule '@microsoft/signalr.` When I change the target toES5 I dont get an error, but in the browser I get then the exception `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true, 
  },

  "compileOnSave": true, 
}
```

Comment: What is your tsconfig? Or what module settings do you use ?

Comment: I added my tsconfig

Answer (score 1):

The `module` option has a different default based on `target` and the `moduleResolution` option has a different default value based on the `module` option. From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> `--module` `target === "ES3" or "ES5" ? "CommonJS" : "ES6"`
>
> `--moduleResolution`  `module === "AMD" or "System" or "ES6" ? "Classic" : "Node"`

This is what lead to the change in behavior. You should probably specify these options explicitly. What will probably work for your case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "module": "CommonJS", 
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },

  "compileOnSave": true, 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately i still get that "exports" is not defined.

Comment: I guess because I dont have CommonJS on my browser? Is there a way without installing a module lib?

Comment: You can change the `module` to `ES2015` with `"moduleResolution": "node"`. But you will have to adjust your imports to be compatible with the browser. And imports like `@microsoft/signalr` will not work in the browser without extra libs

Comment: I was not aware that imports with @ do not work. Is the only alternative, that I import signalr as a file without npm?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [tutorial on the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for using SignalR with Typescript it will get you set up with Webpack. Then you set your tsconfig.json to have `"moduleResolution": "node"` like Titian Cernicova-Dragomir mentioned.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```